# MAUI .Net 7 VS22 cannot see Window Machine screen after build/deploy

Tags: visual-studio-2022, maui, .net-7.0

.net 6 works perfectly for me , but when I create a new project and set .net 7 as a target, I cannot see anything on the screen when I run the project, here is the log :

```
Creating a new clean layout...
Copying files: Total 105 mb to layout...
Checking whether required frameworks are installed...
Registering the application to run from layout...
Deployment complete (0:00:04.411). Full package name: "8cc8c370-e3bb-40df-a37b-e1408483996c_1.0.0.1_x64__9zz4h110yvjzm"
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:24.190 ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Elapsed 00:24.192 ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you could restart and update Visual Studio and create a new project to see if it works.

If it doesn't works, I also find a similar issue on Github : [MAUI apps crash on launch on Windows after Visual Studio update](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080) . You could follow this issue.

The following workaround was mentioned in this issue,

1.[Dayjay comments](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080#issuecomment-1351322492) suggests to run app just build as Admin;

2.[Redth comments](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12080#issuecomment-1398635826) also concludes four ways to solve this issue;

Hope it works for you.